# How to execute a code clicking on arrows / Changing images clicking on arrows using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, swap

I've got code which is supposed to change images on click. It also changes currently chosen image's border color. I'm quite happy about it, it works nicely but I'd like to add arrows to navigate between next and previous images.

jQuery

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('li.switch img, li.switch1 img').click(function() {
      var current = this;
      var elements = $("#w2s, #swap, #swap2");
      var src = this.src;
    $(elements).css("border", "3px solid #fff");
    $(current).css("border", "3px solid  #000");
    $("#w1s").fadeOut(400, function(){
      $(this).fadeIn(400)[0].src = src; 
    });
  });
});
```

HTML

```
   <div class="bottlesWrapper">
    <img src="right.png" id="right">
    <img src="left.png" id="left">
  <div class="thumbs">
    <img src="pallets.jpg" id="w1s">
  </div>

  <ul class="switchPhoto">
   <li class="switch1">
   <img src="pallets.jpg" id="w2s">
  </li>

  <li class="switch">
   <img src="prod.jpg" id="swap">
  </li>

  <li class="switch">
      <img src="modernhome.jpg" id="swap2">
  </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

How can I do so? Can I transform this code to make it happen or is there a whole different solution for this problem?

`#w2s, #swap, #swap2` are the images positioned below the main photo on the top, with id `w1s`

## JSFiddle

Here's how it works
https://jsfiddle.net/hcqozm4e/4/

Comment: can you include the html, and anything you've tried to make work?

Comment: Here it is @depperm. Should I include CSS too?

Comment: A.Snippet or bin will be better. B. Why can't you use a plugin for this?

Comment: Well, I'd really like to use a plugin, but I have no idea how to do so. Could you tell me what is a plugin, @MoshFeu?

Comment: Let Google answer you: [What is pluhin jQuery](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=what+is+pluin+jquery&oq=what+is+pluin+jquery&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.15238j0j4&client=ms-android-om-lge&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#q=what+is+plugin+jquery). Example of Slideshow plugin: http://www.slidesjs.com